# Android - Custom EditText prefix color

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've created a prefix modification for my custom `EditText` by the help of SO and Copy Paste.

Here's the particular code for prefix :

```
private String mPrefix = "";
private Rect mPrefixRect = new Rect();

public OpenSansEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    applyPrefix(context, attrs);
}

public OpenSansEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    applyPrefix(context, attrs);
}


private void applyPrefix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OpenSansET);
    String fontFace;

    try {
        fontFace = a.getString(R.styleable.OpenSansET_prefix);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
    if (fontFace != null){
        mPrefix = fontFace;
    } else {
        mPrefix = "";
    }
}

protected void setmPrefix(String prefix){
    this.mPrefix = prefix;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (!mPrefix.equals("")){
        getPaint().getTextBounds(mPrefix, 0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefixRect);
        mPrefixRect.right += getPaint().measureText(" "); // add some offset
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!mPrefix.equals("")) {
        canvas.drawText(mPrefix, super.getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getBaseline(), getPaint());
    }
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
    return mPrefix.equals("") ? super.getCompoundPaddingLeft()
            : super.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + mPrefixRect.width();
}
```

Basically what it does is if I've supplied a prefix from xml or through code, it draws that prefix onto the start of the `EditText`. For example :

```
<com.asta.classes.OpenSansEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/min"
    app:prefix="$"/>
```

This code produces :

[image: This Image]

But the problem is, if I set `textColorHint`, the color of the prefix will be the same as the color of the hint like :

[image: This Orange Text]

How to modify the color of the prefix to a specified color? In my case it is to let it have its own color rather than using hint color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update **onDraw** method

E.g:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!mPrefix.equals("")) {
        Paint paint = getPaint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawText(mPrefix, super.getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getBaseline(), paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably wanna make that `Paint` object a field, and initialize it elsewhere, especially in an `EditText`.

Comment: This did the trick! But how tho? EDIT : Nevermind, so I just realized I used `getPaint()` blindly. But why does `getPaint()` returns hint color?

Comment: You can override the style, color, size using Paint

Comment: Oh and btw, do you know why, normally if I use styleable, I can get the styleable name by using `ctrl+space` in xml, now for some reason, I have to type it in manually, like `app:prefix=...` rather than typing `pre` then `ctrl+space`?

Comment: This is problem with android studio intellisense, it doesn't show properly for custom styleable attributes

Comment: Oh I see, it wasn't like that before I added an extra attribute. Ok thanks then!

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans_Semibold.ttf");


SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String a = "$" + " ";

SpannableString aSpannable = new SpannableString(a);

aSpannable.setSpan(newForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_yellow)), 0, a.length(), 0);

aSpannable.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, a.length(),    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

builder.append(aSpannable);



String b = "Min";

SpannableString bSpannable = new SpannableString(b);

bSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white)), 0, b.length(), 0);


bSpannable.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, b.length(),       Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

builder.append(bSpannable);


final EditText textV = new EditText(this); 

textV.setHint(builder,textV.BufferType.SPANNABLE)`
```

Comment: Ahh the custom TypefaceSpan.. I've been using that too, but that's not the prefix I meant haha, thanks though, see my posted code and the accepted answer for how to